# How to apply multiple rewrite_rule to a single custom post type url?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have created a custom post type named `bollywood`, and a rewrite rule in order to map a URL such as `example.com/bollywood/old-movies-of-hero1-with-hero2` to the query `index.php?post_type=bollywood&hero1=hero1&hero2=hero2`:

```php
add_rewrite_rule( 
  '^bollywood/old-movies-of-([^/]+)-to-([^/]+)/?$',
  'index.php?post_type=bollywood&hero1=$matches[1]&hero2=$matches[2]',
  'top'
);
```

Currently, single `bollywood` posts are available at a permalink like `domain/bollywood/hero1` - how can I present them at `domain/bollywood/old-movies-of-hero1` instead?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it seems like your post type should be `hero` and `bollywood` should be an entry in a new taxonomy.  Hero1, Hero2, etc would be individual posts under your `hero` post type.  Bollywood, Hollywood, Nollywood (yes), Chinese, etc would be entries under a `location` taxonomy.

Comment: what ever the post type or post should be the main question is 
when we write single post it shows like as 
domain/slug/old-movies-of-post1(any post name)
and when two it will be
domain/slug/old-movies-of-post1-with-post2

it works for 2 post as mentioned I want for for single url like this
domain/slug/old-movies-of-post1(any post name)